# Peeking the next row

Tags: java, pentaho

I want to delete some tags out of my xml with help of PDI. I only need 1 mime of each type per Product. I thought I can write a User Defined Java Class for it, but I need to peek the next row when I'm at the first node. My xml looks like this:

```
<MIME_INFO>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/tiff</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>P_I202_XX_06499E600600.TIF</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>detail</MIME_PURPOSE>
                </MIME>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>P_I202_XX_06499I300300.JPG</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
                </MIME>
                <MIME>
                    <MIME_TYPE>image/jpeg</MIME_TYPE>
                    <MIME_SOURCE>P_I202_XX_00482I300300.JPG</MIME_SOURCE>
                    <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
                </MIME>
            </MIME_INFO>
```

I process the rows line by line with the main UDJC function, but when I'm at the  row I have to know the type of the mime to know if I have to skip it or not. How can I peek on the next row? Something like getNextRow() or getRow(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... just had to call the getRow once more, but to store the first row in a temp variable. Then after finding out what was in the second row, I could decide if I wanted to process the first row or not (if my line contained a MIME node, i processed 2 rows in one step).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like DOM parser in order to parse your XML file.
The approach you are using might work well but its not a good way do it.
you can refer below link for reading an xml file,and then you can perform your manipulations accordingly:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/